# I cant find the files I save in vim

Tags: linux, vim

I am trying to learn code using a vim editor as I hear I can get superior long term benefits when I start making long codes and documents. I am a pretty big fan of keyboard shortcuts so I do not mind taking the long road to superior editing abilities. Any way the Linux book I am reading has recommended it and even has many exercises that require typing and saving in vim. The problem is that I cannot find the files I save in vim. I enter the escape mode hit the colon key and use the w option. The vim tells me that the file is saved but when  later try to find it in my Linux directory I can find nothing. I have tried using the type, file, find, and locate commands as well as whereis even though this is for commands. Thank you for help in advance.

Comment: you can try in the vim file : `ESC ` `:`   `!$PWD` enter to see were the file you are running the file you are working on

Comment: Or `ESC` `:pwd`.
By the way, for `locate` to work on a newly created file, you'll want to run `sudo updatedb` first. Check the man pages (`man <command>`) for more details.
`find` should work. Please look at the Unix/Ubuntu/Superuser StackExchange sites for an existing answer to your issue if you find the man page for `find` to be too overwhelming. Only post a new question if there's no good existing answer. Remember to include your *exact* command, the results that you were expecting, and the results that you got.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: try using `vimtutor` to get more comfortable with the basics of vim.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as escape mode. Most likely you are referring to normal mode. The easiest way to enter normal mode is by hitting the escape key, <kbd>Esc</kbd>. Once in normal mode you can save the contents of the current buffer into the file by typing `:w`. Alternatively you can specify a new file name with `:w filename`. Then you can quit vim with `:q`. These steps can be combined by typing `:wq`.

You mention that Vim tells you the file has been saved but you cannot find the file. In this case type `Ctrl-g` after saving the file, the file name relative to the current directory should be displayed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.I figured it out. Vim saves by default in the home directory

Answer (score 0):

Your "Linux book" almost certainly tells you to do something like:

```
$ vim filename
```

with `filename` being an existing file or a non-existing file. In both cases, doing `:w<CR>` in Vim, will write `filename`…

- in the working directory if `filename` is just a file name, without anything "path-like":

  ```
  $ cd /tmp
  $ vim foo.txt
  (do your thing)
  :wq
  $ echo $PWD/$_
  /tmp/foo.txt
  ```
- at the given location relative to the working directory if `filename` is a relative path:

  ```
  $ cd ~/Documents
  $ vim exercices/foo.txt
  (do your thing)
  :wq
  $ echo $PWD/$_
  /home/rubberbandface/Documents/exercices/foo.txt
  ```
- at the given location if `filename` is an absolute path:

  ```
  $ vim ~/Documents/exercices/foo.txt
  (do your thing)
  :wq
  $ echo $_
  /home/rubberbandface/Documents/exercices/foo.txt
  ```

---

That said, you shouldn't learn Linux, Vim, and programming at the same time.

Comment: Thank you so much for the comments here. I figured it out. Vim saves by default in the home directory. I had to use `ls -l` in a couple directories manually to find it. Still a newb. I am reading The Linux Command Line form No Starch Press btw. Great book.

Comment: No. Vim saves by default in *the working directory*.